# Права доступа к папке хранения временных файлов 777

Tags: php, файлы

Подскажите, как изменить права доступа к файлам временного хранения 777?

Ошибка:

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/blurb_temporary/personall.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/index.php on line 106 Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/var/www/atai/data/mod-tmp/phpHztowa' to
>   '/var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/blurb_temporary/personall.jpg' in
>   /var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/index.php on line 106

Код:

```
$uploaddir='/var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/blurb_temporary';
$tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_link,trim($_FILES['image']['name']));

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$uploaddir/$image")){ 
    $add_success='<p class="success">Ваша реклама успешно добавлена</p>';
    return $add_success.$form;
    }
else {
    $error='<p class="error">'.'Ошибка сервера. Попытайтесь еще раз'.'</p>';
    return $error.$form;
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте @mkdir("path_to_dir",0777);

Comment: не работает, ошибка какая-та

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы изменить права на файл\папку в клиенте FTP Нажмите правой кнопкой на файл\папку - file attributes - ставьте нужные атрибуты.

ВНИМАНИЕ! Что бы это работало у вашего FTP user должны быть соответствующие права, если таковых нет то обратитесь к администратору FTP сервера

Answer (score 0):

открыть консоль в каталоге `/var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/blurb_temporary/` и выполнить `chmod 777 .`

Comment: anber, но у меня же доступ к файлам только через filezilla.

Comment: Значит попросите того у кого есть доступ

Answer (score 0):

Если vps/vds, то в терминале :

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/atai/data/www/atai.krsu.kg/blurb_temporary
```

Если хостинг (а у тебя скорее всего хостинг), то в веб-морде должен быть диспетчер файлов. Там можно поменять права доступа на папку `blurb_temporary`