# В файле загрузки фотографий на сайт выдает ошибку, помогите исправить

Tags: php, warning

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(temp/Klipsch_RP-140WM_1.jpg)
> [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission
> denied in /var/www/topcomfort/topcomfort.com.ua/tools/prods_single.php
> on line 126
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to
> move '/var/www/topcomfort/tmp/phpPwHCOv' to
> 'temp/Klipsch_RP-140WM_1.jpg' in
> /var/www/topcomfort/topcomfort.com.ua/tools/prods_single.php on line
> 126

```
$k=0; while(1){if(file_exists('../images/small/'.$img.$img_ext)){$img = $img.$k;} else {break;}  $k++;} //если есть совпадение

$img = $img.$img_ext;

$tmp_name = $_FILES["image_file_".$i]["tmp_name"];
```

**строка 126:** `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "temp/".$img);`

```
$rz_image = mysql_query("SELECT image FROM products_images WHERE products_id = ".$_POST['id']);
while($image2show = mysql_fetch_array($rz_image)){
    if(@file("temp/".$img) == @file("../images/originals/".$image2show['image'])) {$doubled = 1;}
    $fotoz_amount++;
}
if(!$doubled){
    if(file_exists('temp/'.$img)) {
        $img_old = $img;
        $img = save_img('temp/'.$img_old);
```

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что паки `temp` или не существует, или ей не хватает прав.

Нужно выполнить команду в SSH консоли `chmod -R 777 temp/` или через файловый менеджер выбрать Свойства папки и выставить все права на запись.

Этот вопрос уже рассматривали здесь: [Права доступа к папке хранения временных файлов 777](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416735/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-777?rq=1)